Parcel giving me "failed to resolve error" and "Invalid empty specifier" even though I specified my path
I am currently having a big issue involving my sass compilation using Parcel. My issue seems to be coming from one of two imports in my main.scss file. Here is my main.scss file.
@use 'layout'; //this import works
@use 'pages'; //this import seems to be the one causing the issue

This is the error I am getting:
@parcel/core: Failed to resolve '' from './src/styles/scss/main.scss'

C:\Users\netog\OneDrive\Desktop\Horizons\src\styles\scss\main.scss:30:5

@parcel/resolver-default: Invalid empty specifier

The 'pages' import points to an index.scss file containing all the stylized files that I am forwarding into the main.scss file. The page's path seems to work as it opens up my index.scss file. Here is my index.scss file:
@forward 'about';
@forward 'home';
@forward 'aboutBlockchain';
@forward 'aboutMinting';
@forward 'aboutNFTs';
@forward 'aboutWallets';
@forward 'aboutHorizons';
@forward 'blog';
@forward 'collectionPage';
@forward 'connectWallet';
@forward 'contact';
@forward 'login';
@forward 'profile';
@forward 'signup';
@forward 'subscription';

And finally, I will provide a screenshot of my project structure. I am assuming it has something to do with how I set up my project but I have no idea what is going on.
Screenshot of my project directory/structure
I tried using different paths for the page file yet I am still getting the same error. I also tried deleting the parcel cache and dist folder, yet the same error still shows.
